# How to Continuous Integration tools check status of test process (like building, fail, success)

Tags: php, tdd, integration, continuous, calabash

I use php to develop a tool where user can upload their apk file and test write in Calabash

They click run test then my tool will run this test and return result for user

I use exec() in php to run test command (in window), then push result to a txt file

So i dont know how to check when test end to notify to user via email and show status of test process, can any one help me?

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Use a database table called jobs. When a user submits an upload, create a row in the database table with a status of 'uploaded'. Then, when exec() runs, update the database table row to have a status of 'running', when exec() finished update the table row to have a status of 'complete'.

To email end user when it's finished, use a cron job that runs every X minutes. In that cron job, query the database for status 'complete' within the past X minutes.

To show the end user on a page, use Javascript and AJAX to hit a PHP script every few seconds asking for the status of that job ID.